# Angular - Passing data to child components with contentChildren not working with 2 nested levels

Tags: angular, typescript

My goal is to have the following structure:

```
<app-parent color="red">
    <app-container>
        <app-child></app-child>
        <app-child></app-child>
    </app-container>
</app-parent>
```

I want to set the color only on the parent component. The `ContainerComponent` should get the color from the `ParentComponent` implicitly and the `ChildComponent` should get the color from its parent-component `ContainerComponent`.

The `ContainerComponent` gets its color correctly from the `ParentComponent` but when i go a level deeper, the `ChildComponent` doesn't get the color from the `ContainerComponent` :-(

The parent-component only contains a `ng-content`-element.

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-parent",
  template: `
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  `,
  styles: []
})
```

With the help of `ContentChildren` i get all ContainerComponents and pass them a color in the `ngAfterContentInit()`

```
@ContentChildren(ContainerComponent) contents: QueryList<ContainerComponent>;
ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.contents.forEach((content, i) => {
      content.color = this.color;
    });
  }
```

The ContainerComponents gets the color as input and it works.
But when in the ContainerComponent i want to pass the color with the same `ContentChildren`-Method to the `ChildComponent` it doesn't work!

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-container",
  template: `
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let c of contents">
            <ng-content></ng-content>
        </li>
    </ul>
  `,
  styles: []
})
export class ContainerComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() color;

  constructor() { }

  @ContentChildren(ChildComponent) contents: QueryList<ChildComponent>;

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.contents.forEach((content, i) => {
      content.color = this.color; //<-- this.color is undefined!
    });
  }
}
```

The `this.color` property is undefined on this level. So it could not set the color on the `ChildComponent` right. But why it works on the top level and not a level deeper?

[My Plunker to this example](https://plnkr.co/edit/vM5NNa3RyMkZ1Y92MOWf?p=preview)

I expect to  get a list(ul with li) with two red divs but i get only two divs in a list without a red color :-(

Is this a bug or by design? In react this structure can be build easy with `props.children` and `React.Children.map`

Comment: onAfterContentInit of parent comes after the one of the child and you try to have the value of the parent in ContainerComponent but it's not set yet

Comment: How to solve this? Use something like onChange or another Hook